# Python Requests library returns wrong status code

Tags: python-2.7, http-status-code-403, python-requests

The Python code below returns '403':

```
import requests
url = 'http://bedstardirect.co.uk/star-collection-braemar-double-bedstead.html'
r = requests.get(url)
print r.status_code
```

But this page is valid and the script should return '200', as does the perl script below:

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
my $url = 'http://bedstardirect.co.uk/star-collection-braemar-double-bedstead.html';
$mech->get($url);
print $mech->status,"\n";
```

I have also checked with Firebug in Firefox and all requests have a '200' status code.

I use Python Requests v1.2.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems your particular server requires a User-Agent header.

Try:
`r = requests.get('http://bedstardirect.co.uk/star-collection-braemar-double-bedstead.html', headers={'User-Agent': 'a user agent'})`

Edit:
The default User-Agent on requests for my machine comes out as: `python-requests/1.2.0 CPython/2.7.4 Darwin/12.3.0`

After some testing I found that any User-Agent that contains the word `python` will fail on this server.

Comment: That's odd since requests sends one by default.